# Mvc Core Identity Authorization for Website & JwtBearer for WebApi in the same application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, jwt

I have a MVC Core application which has implemented Identity based on [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Now I need to add rest API for an Android application and implement JWT tokens for mobiles so I set startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    AddScopedServices(services);

    services.AddCors();
    services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

    AddDbServices(services);
                services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>();

    services.AddAuthorization(
        options => { options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin")); }
        );


    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // Password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
        // Lockout settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
        // User settings
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    });

    services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();
    services.AddRazorPages();


// --- JWT start
        var jwtSection = Configuration.GetSection("JwtBearerTokenSettings");
    services.Configure<JwtBearerTokenSettings>(jwtSection);

    var jwtBearerTokenSettings = jwtSection.Get<JwtBearerTokenSettings>();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtBearerTokenSettings.SecretKey);

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = jwtBearerTokenSettings.Issuer,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = jwtBearerTokenSettings.Audience,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        });
// --- JWT end

}
```

Once I added JWT configuration I cannot login using Identity using web browser. I guess that JWT requires a token from all clients, not just from [ApiController] designated for rest clients.
This is how I generate JWT token:

```
private object GenerateToken(ApplicationUser identityUser)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtBearerTokenSettings.SecretKey);

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, identityUser.UserName.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, identityUser.Email)
        }),

        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(jwtBearerTokenSettings.ExpiryTimeInSeconds),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),
        Audience = jwtBearerTokenSettings.Audience,
        Issuer = jwtBearerTokenSettings.Issuer
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

and my Login method for standard webbrowers users:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var identityUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.UserName);
                        ///what should it do now with this token:
            var token = GenerateToken(identityUser);
                        ///what should it do now with this token:
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: would you please provide error

Comment: just a reminder you forced role admin to authorize with owin

Comment: where is it? policy?

Comment: options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin")); }

Comment: good point.. it solved the problem :)